# Need help understanding relationship between DOM elements & Objects created in a class

Tags: javascript

```
class Button {
    constructor(name) {
        this.target = 'bullseye';
        this.name = name;
        this.element = this.create();
    }
    create() {
        var button_html = '<div>'+this.name+'</div>';
        var button_element = $(button_html);
        button_element[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Button.yell('??????');
            //Should be buttonA, or buttonB depending on which one was clicked. I have tried, (this) & (e), but to no success.
        }); 
        $('body').append(button_element);
        return button_element;
    }

    static yell(element){
        alert('You have hit the '+element.target);
    }


}

let buttonA = new Button('Button A');
let buttonB = new Button('Button B');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x4dsgp5b/1/

I feel I'm misunderstanding some very basic stuff here. What is the proper syntax/logic to place a [clickable] button onto the body from a Class, and interact with buttonA or buttonB (depending on which was clicked).

Comment: Have you tried Button.yell(button_element)?

Comment: Just tried, no success :(

Comment: `Button.yell` is a static method.  Trying to access `this.target` within a static method, doesn't make sense.  Since it is a static method you will want to pass in an argument to access the target or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only the name and use the `this` property to get the current button.

Then in the click handler you know by name which button has been clicked.

Something like here:

```js
class Button {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.element = this.create();
    }
    
    create() {
        const element = document.createElement("button"); 
        element.innerHTML = `<div>${this.name}</div>`;
        element.addEventListener('click', this.yell.bind(this))
       
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        
        return element;
    }

    yell() {
        alert('You have hit the '+this.name);
    }
}

const buttonA = new Button('Button A');
const buttonB = new Button('Button B');
```

### Some notes:

- I have used the new ES6 synax (no var or let when not needed)
- I didn't use jquery (the example was simple to be done in pure JavaScript)
- I used `this.yell` as direct handler for click, in order to have the good `this` I have to bind it
- I need the `this` property in yell function in order to know the name, that's why I removed the static keyword.

Comment: this.yell.bind(this) seems to be the key! It appears to link the dom element to the object. Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: the `bind(this)` is just to pass the good current class lexical context `this` into the handler function. Otherwise it will not have the same this, and when you do `this.name` the name will be undefined.

Comment: check more on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: you can also do like this if you don't want to use bind: `element.addEventListener('click', () => this.yell.bind())` This creates a new function but keeps the current `this` or current context (Ths is how arrow functions works)

Comment: The arrow function has helped a ton! It allows me to button_element[0].addEventListener('click', (){ //alert('You have hit the'+this.target)});

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this one works.

```js
class Button {
    constructor(name) {
        this.target = 'bullseye';
        this.name = name;
        this.element = this.create();
    }
    create() {
        var buttone = document.createElement("div");
        buttone.innerHTML = this.name;
    
        document.body.appendChild(buttone);
        let _name = this.name;
        buttone.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Button.yell(_name);
        }); 
        
        return buttone;
    }

    static yell(element){
        alert('You have hit the '+element);
    }


}

let buttonA = new Button('Button A');
let buttonB = new Button('Button B');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work! You already have a function (Button.yell) that accepts the element.

```
button_element[0].addEventListener('click', Button.yell);
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is that you want the alert to say the word 'Button A' or 'Button B'.

```
button_element[0].addEventListener(
     'click', 
     (e) => Button.yell(this.name)
);
```

Note that I used the arrow function syntax (`=>`) rather than the funtion syntax. The reason for this is that, if you use the function syntax, the `this` value will be different within the handler function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the goal is have the alert say "You have hit the bullseye".